# Need help with evaluating a difficult integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have the integral shown below after working out the electric field at some point z above a hollow sphere with charge density per unit area of $\sigma$

> $$\frac{\sigma}{4\pi\epsilon }\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{R}\frac{r^{2}\sin\phi dr d \theta d\phi }{\left [ z^{2}+r^{2}-2zr\cos\phi \right ]}
> - 
> \frac{\sigma}{4\pi\epsilon }\int_{\phi=0}^{\pi}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{R}
> \frac{r^{3}\sin\phi \cos\phi dr d \theta d\phi }{\left [ z^{2}+r^{2}-2zr\cos\phi \right ]}$$

But this integral proves to be exceeding hard to break down. Where do I start?
Clear workings would be utmost helpful.

Comment: If the sphere is hollow, you shouldn't need to integrate over $r$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Why is this so?

Comment: Because all the charge is on the surface $r=R$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I realise. 
More pertinently, how should I attack the integral?

Comment: Is this from Griffiths? You may want to check out http://www.physicspages.com/index-electrodynamics/griffiths-introduction-to-electrodynamics-problems/

Comment: @zahbaz Sharp eyes!

Comment: @Mathematicing Two terms have different dimensions.  Any typos?

Comment: @NgChungTak I've check. No typos.

Comment: I realize I'm over two years late to the party, but I just finished a course that used Griffiths, and I recognized this problem, having solved it with a similar amount of frustration to that which you seem to have experienced. Would you mind if I were to add an answer pointing out the small mistakes in your integral and showing how to solve it, for the reference of any other students who turn to the internet for help with this monstrosity?

Comment: @RobertHoward No, please go ahead!

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to start with the original problem statement and work from there, since there are a few small mistakes in that integral you've got up there. This is Problem 2.7 in Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics* (Fourth Edition).

[image]
[image]

Let $\mathbf{r}$ be the vector from any point on the sphere's surface to $P$ (because that script $\mathbf{r}$ that Griffiths uses is annoyingly hard to type in MathJax), and let $r$ be its length. Also, let $\alpha$ be the angle between $\mathbf{r}$ and the $z$-axis, and let $\phi$ be the azimuthal angle. Then, as in the figure, $\theta$ is the polar angle, $R$ is the radius of the sphere, and $z$ is the distance from the center of the sphere to $P$.

Since the surface of the sphere has a total charge $q$ distributed with a uniform density $\sigma$, each infinitesimal part $dA$ of the sphere's surface carries an infinitesimal piece of charge $dq=\sigma dA$. Expressing that in spherical coordinates, we have $dq=\sigma R^2 \sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi$.

We can see from the symmetry of the problem setup that any horizontal components of the electric field at $P$ will cancel out, so $\mathbf{E}=E_z\hat{\mathbf{z}}$, which simplifies things a bit -- we only need to find $E_z$.

Now, Coulomb's law tells us that the strength of the electric field generated by each infinitesimal piece of charge $dq$ is
$$dE=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{dq}{r^2}.$$

More specifically, in this case (at $P$),
$$dE=dE_z=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{dq}{r^2}\cos\alpha,$$
where we need the $\cos\alpha$ term to represent the contribution to the electric field at $P$ from all points other than the one directly between $P$ and the center of the sphere.

Since we have $dE_z$ at the moment, the logical thing to do is to integrate to find $E_z$, but we're going to need to re-express some terms first. $dq$ (as we've already seen), $r^2$, and $\cos\alpha$ can all be re-expressed in terms of combinations of variables over which we're going to integrate and constants.

By the law of cosines,
$$r^2=R^2+z^2-2Rz\cos\theta.$$

We can also re-express $\cos\alpha$ in a similar way:
$$\begin{align}
R^2&=r^2+z^2-2rz\cos\alpha \\
\cos\alpha&=\frac{R^2-r^2-z^2}{-2rz} \\
&=\frac{r^2+z^2-R^2}{2rz} \\
&=\frac{R^2+z^2-2Rz\cos\theta+z^2-R^2}{2z\sqrt{R^2+z^2-2Rz\cos\theta}} \\
&=\frac{2z(z-R\cos\theta)}{2z\sqrt{R^2+z^2-2Rz\cos\theta}} \\
&=\frac{z-R\cos\theta}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2-2Rz\cos\theta}}
\end{align}$$

Pulling everything together, we have:
$$\begin{align}
dE_z&=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\sigma R^2 \sin\theta\ d\theta\ d\phi}{R^2+z^2-2Rz\cos\theta}\frac{z-R\cos\theta}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2-2Rz\cos\theta}} \\
&=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\sigma R^2 \sin\theta(z-R\cos\theta)}{(R^2+z^2-2Rz\cos\theta)^{3/2}}d\theta\ d\phi
\end{align}$$

Now we can integrate. Since $\theta$ is the polar angle, we have $0\le\theta\le\pi$, and since $\phi$ is the azimuthal angle, we have $0\le\phi\le2\pi$; note that the definitions of $\theta$ and $\phi$ I use are the opposite of those you used in your integral. Note also that since $dr$ never appeared in our earlier calculations, there's no need to integrate over $r$.

Rearranging a little bit, our integral emerges at last:
$$E_z=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\sigma R^2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin\theta(z-R\cos\theta)}{(R^2+z^2-2Rz\cos\theta)^{3/2}}d\theta\ d\phi$$

That's a mess. Let's see what we can do about that.

---

It's easy to integrate over $\phi$ first, since $\phi$ doesn't appear anywhere in the integrand; that simplifies the integral a little bit, to this:
$$E_z=\frac1{2\epsilon_0}\sigma R^2\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin\theta(z-R\cos\theta)}{(R^2+z^2-2Rz\cos\theta)^{3/2}}d\theta$$

We can now make the substitution $u=z-R\cos\theta$, and once we do that, a few interesting things happen:
$$\begin{align}
du&=R\sin\theta\ d\theta \implies \frac1Rdu=\sin\theta\ d\theta \\
\theta&=0 \implies u=z-R\cos(0)=z-R \\
\theta&=\pi \implies u=z-R\cos(\pi)=z+R \\
u&=z-R\cos\theta \implies R\cos\theta=z-u
\end{align}$$

Plugging all of that back into the integral, we have:
$$\begin{align}
E_z&=\frac1{2\epsilon_0}\sigma R^2\int_{z-R}^{z+R}\frac{\frac1Ru}{(R^2+z^2-2z(z-u))^{3/2}}du \\
&=\frac1{2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\int_{z-R}^{z+R}\frac{u}{(R^2+z^2-2z^2+2zu)^{3/2}}du \\
&=\frac1{2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\int_{z-R}^{z+R}\frac{u}{(R^2-z^2+2zu)^{3/2}}du
\end{align}$$

Let's make another substitution now: $v=R^2-z^2+2zu$. This has similar effects to the last substitution:
$$\begin{align}
u&=\frac1{2z}(v-R^2+z^2) \\
dv&=2z\ du \implies \frac1{2z}dv=du
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
u=z-R \implies v&=R^2-z^2+2z(z-R) \\
&=R^2-z^2+2z^2-2zR \\
&=R^2+z^2-2zR \\
&=(R-z)^2 \\
u=z+R \implies v&=R^2-z^2+2z(z+R) \\
&=R^2-z^2+2z^2+2zR \\
&=R^2+z^2+2zR \\
&=(R+z)^2
\end{align}$$

Our integral now looks like this:
$$\begin{align}
E_z&=\frac1{2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\int_{(R-z)^2}^{(R+z)^2}\frac{\frac1{2z}(v-R^2+z^2)}{v^{3/2}}\frac1{2z}dv \\
&=\frac1{8z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\int_{(R-z)^2}^{(R+z)^2}\frac{v-R^2+z^2}{v^{3/2}}dv \\
&=\frac1{8z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\int_{(R-z)^2}^{(R+z)^2}\left[v^{-1/2}-(R^2-z^2)v^{-3/2}\right]dv
\end{align}$$

Much more manageable, right? At long last, we can evaluate it!
$$\begin{align}
E_z&=\frac1{8z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[2v^{1/2}+2(R^2-z^2)v^{-1/2}\right]\Bigg|_{(R-z)^2}^{(R+z)^2} \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[v^{1/2}+(R^2-z^2)v^{-1/2}\right]\Bigg|_{(R-z)^2}^{(R+z)^2} \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[\sqrt{(R+z)^2}+\frac{R^2-z^2}{\sqrt{(R+z)^2}}-\sqrt{(R-z)^2}-\frac{R^2-z^2}{\sqrt{(R-z)^2}}\right] \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[R+z+\frac{R^2-z^2}{R+z}-\sqrt{(R-z)^2}-\frac{R^2-z^2}{\sqrt{(R-z)^2}}\right]
\end{align}$$

I agree that it looks a little weird to leave the $(R-z)^2$ terms under the square roots, but remember the second part of the hint from the problem statement? That's going to come into play now. We have two distinct cases, where $z\lt R$ (in other words, where $P$ is inside the sphere), and where $z\gt R$ (where $P$ is outside the sphere). The value of $\sqrt{(R-z)^2}$ will be different in each case, since we always want to avoid taking the square root of a negative number.

---

### **If $P$ is inside the sphere $(z\lt R)$:**

$$\begin{align}
E_z&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[R+z+\frac{R^2-z^2}{R+z}-\sqrt{(R-z)^2}-\frac{R^2-z^2}{\sqrt{(R-z)^2}}\right] \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[R+z+\frac{R^2-z^2}{R+z}-R+z-\frac{R^2-z^2}{R-z}\right] \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[2z+\frac{(R^2-z^2)(R-z)-(R^2-z^2)(R+z)}{R^2-z^2}\right] \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[2z+\frac{(R^2-z^2)(R-z-R-z)}{R^2-z^2}\right] \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[2z-\frac{2z(R^2-z^2)}{R^2-z^2}\right] \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left(2z-2z\right) \\
&=0
\end{align}$$

### **If $P$ is outside the sphere $(z\gt R)$:**

$$\begin{align}
E_z&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[R+z+\frac{R^2-z^2}{R+z}-\sqrt{(R-z)^2}-\frac{R^2-z^2}{\sqrt{(R-z)^2}}\right] \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[R+z+\frac{R^2-z^2}{R+z}-z+R-\frac{R^2-z^2}{z-R}\right] \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[2R+\frac{(R^2-z^2)(z-R)-(R^2-z^2)(R+z)}{z^2-R^2}\right] \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[2R+\frac{(R^2-z^2)(z-R-R-z)}{z^2-R^2}\right] \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[2R-\frac{2R(R^2-z^2)}{z^2-R^2}\right] \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left[2R+\frac{2R(z^2-R^2)}{z^2-R^2}\right] \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left(2R+2R\right) \\
&=\frac1{4z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R\left(4R\right) \\
&=\frac1{z^2\epsilon_0}\sigma R^2 \\
&=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{z^2} \qquad\qquad (\text{since}\ q=4\pi R^2\sigma)
\end{align}$$

---

And there you have it!
$$\mathbf{E}=
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{0}, & z\lt R \\[1ex]
\displaystyle{\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{z^2}}\hat{\mathbf{z}}, & z\gt R
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using symmetry and Gauss's theorem, rather than integration.  The electric field is radially symmetric, and by Gauss's theorem its magnitude at distance $z$ from the centre depends only on the amount of charge at distances $< r$ from the centre.  So the electric field outside the sphere is the same as if you put all that charge at the origin.

Comment: That is true. One can use Gauss's theorem to compute the Field in principle. But the question requires me to compute this without resort to Gauss's theorem...

Comment: I've been trying for the past 2 hours with no results. Can you expound on what you mean by "all the charge at the origin"?

Comment: Charge density $\sigma$ per unit area, area $4 \pi R^2$, so charge $4 \pi R^2 \sigma$.  Same field as produced by a charge $4 \pi R^2 \sigma$ at the origin.