# How do we solve the given integral to reach the given solution?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I encountered this integral given below.

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{z-Ru}{(R^2+z^2-2Rzu)^{3/2}}\mathop {\mathrm du}$$

The recommended answer is
$$\frac1{z^2}\left\{\frac{z-R}{|z-R|}-\frac{-z-R}{|z+R|}\right\}$$

Although I can solve this by separating the terms in the numerator and then substituting for the expression in the denominator within the brackets as $y^2$. This will pose two conditions: either $z>R$ or $R>z$, in which case I must find the final expression for each condition separately.

However, I am desperate to know how to obtain the elegant expression as given in the recommended answer.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659462/need-help-with-evaluating-a-difficult-integral/2853904#2853904) seems to be a [popular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2531701/integral-for-electric-field?rq=1) [integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226547/need-help-with-integral-to-evaluate-electric-field-around-a-spherical-shell?rq=1) on MSE; perhaps one of the answers to those questions will help shed some light on the situation for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First consider the integral
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2+2Rzu}}$$
This one is rather easy to calculate an antiderivative for; it is equal to
$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2+2Rzu}}=\frac{1}{Rz}\sqrt{R^2+z^2+2Rzu}$$
and so evaluating across the given limits of integration gives us the answer
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{du}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2+2Rzu}}=\frac{\sqrt{(R+z)^2}-\sqrt{(R-z)^2}}{Rz}$$
Differentiate both sides of this with respect to $z$ and the answer should follow, because the LHS will become
$$-\int_{-1}^1 \frac{z+Ru}{\sqrt{R^2+z^2+2Rzu}}du$$
which turns in to the integral you are looking for if you substitute $z\to -z$.